# Data Structure - Diameter of Polygon

Tags: polygon, convex-hull

I need a data structute that allows

- addPoint(x, y) in O(logN)
- printDiameter() in O(logN)

where N is the current number of points in the polygon.
Obviously the two points will lie on the convex hull of the polygon. Using concept of anti-nodal pairs(Rotating-Callipers), we can find the diameter of N points is O(N).
[This](http://www.tcs.fudan.edu.cn/rudolf/Courses/Algorithms/Alg_ss_07w/Webprojects/Qinbo_diameter/2d_alg.htm) explains neatly the O(n) solution, but it doesn't supports insertion of point.

Answer (score 0):

A k-d tree could do insertion in O(logN) as long as it's [balanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221243/is-kd-tree-always-balanced) in some way. For the diameter part, you would have to check every node in order to find the farthest, so it should be O(N).
Another solution would be to use a QuadTree, and traverse it in order to obtain only the nodes located at the external part of the tree.